# How do I get Angular compilation errors to show in Build for Net Core application?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am creating a Net Core Angular application. It is a Default Net Core Template project. I see compilation errors in the actual typescript files, however do not see them as errors when I Build the project.

How do I show them as errors in the Build Output window?
I am trying to mimic this project, I purposely created an error by placing incorrect directory, and have it show in build.

https://ankitsharmablogs.com/asp-net-core-crud-using-angular-5-and-entity-framework-core/

[image]
Thanks,

File fetchemployee.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';  
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';  
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';  
import { EmployeeService } from '../../../Serviceswrongdirectory/empservice.service'
//import Empserviceservice = require("../../../Services/empservice.service");
//import EmployeeService = Empserviceservice.EmployeeService;

@Component({  
    templateUrl: './fetchemployee.component.html'  
})  

export class FetchEmployeeComponent {  
    public empList: EmployeeData[];  

    constructor(public http: Http, private _router: Router, private _employeeService: EmployeeService) {  
        this.getEmployees();  
    }  

    getEmployees() {  
        this._employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(  
            data => this.empList = data  
        )  
    }  

    delete(employeeID) {  
        var ans = confirm("Do you want to delete customer with Id: " + employeeID);  
        if (ans) {  
            this._employeeService.deleteEmployee(employeeID).subscribe((data) => {  
                this.getEmployees();  
            }, error => console.error(error))  
        }  
    }  
}  

interface EmployeeData {  
    employeeId: number;  
    name: string;  
    gender: string;  
    city: string;  
    department: string;  

}
```

Comment: It depends entirely on how you set up Angular, so we cannot tell you without more information

Comment: ok thanks, tough crowd, started learning Angular today, and was trying to research

Comment: I can almost guarantee the down votes are simply because you took a screen shot of code instead of pasting the snippet in as markdown text.

Comment: Well, I've got news for you. If you actually followed that old article, you are in fact using Angular 6 not 5. Not that it makes a difference here, but you should be aware of that.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Not sure VS is a relevant tag here. I would have kept .NET Core in though as it's relevant to the build process.

Comment: @DavidG It depends whether you want to configure it through Angular, through MSBuild or through Visual Studio's project window

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919126/how-to-trigger-a-ng-build-from-within-a-dotnetcore-web-api-project-with-msbuil), that may help.